# Memory leak when read from file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to read data from XML file and store every element ("< some data/>") in vector container  `vector<TCHAR*>` , why the Task Manager shows the memory usage much greater than vector size(~80mb instead of ~59mb) :

```
#define _UNICODE

#include<tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hThread;
vector<TCHAR*> tokens;
DWORD tokensSize;

DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID lpVoid);


void main()
{   
    tokensSize = 0;
    hFile = CreateFile("db.xml",GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)   {
        cout<<"CreateFile Error # "<<GetLastError()<<endl;      
    }

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile,NULL);
    cout<<"fileSize = "<<fileSize<<" bytes = "<<fileSize/1024/1024<<" mb"<<endl;
    TCHAR* buffer = new TCHAR[fileSize / sizeof(TCHAR) + 1];
    ZeroMemory(buffer,fileSize);

    DWORD bytesRead;
    if(!ReadFile(hFile,buffer,fileSize,&bytesRead,NULL)){
        cout<<"ReadFile Error # "<<GetLastError()<<endl;        
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,Thread,(LPVOID)buffer,0,NULL);    

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);

    for(int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++)
            tokensSize+=(_tcslen(tokens[i])+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
    cout<<"vector size = "<<tokensSize<<" bytes = "<<tokensSize/1024/1024<<" mb"<<endl;
    cin.get();  
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID lpVoid)
{
    wstring entireDB = (TCHAR*)lpVoid;
    delete[]lpVoid; 

    wstring currentElement;
    wstring::size_type lastPos = 0;
    wstring::size_type next;

    next = entireDB.find(_T(">"),lastPos);
    TCHAR* szStr;
    do
    {               
        currentElement = entireDB.substr(lastPos,next+1-lastPos);
        szStr = new TCHAR[currentElement.length()+1];
        _tcscpy(szStr,currentElement.c_str());
        tokens.push_back(szStr);
        lastPos = next+1;
        next = entireDB.find(_T(">"),lastPos);
    }
    while(next != wstring::npos);

    entireDB.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:~
fileSize = 57mb
vectorSize = 58mb

but the TaskManager shows ~ 81mb.
What am I doing wrong?
THNX!

Comment: Mickey, is this file UTF8 XML ? I ask because it appears you're reading it as TCHAR, but that can be either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on the compilaton. There are a number of things wrong with this code but I wanted to know a few more things (this being one of them) prior to posting a response. Also, are you building with Visual Studio or are you using MinGW, the bare Windows SDK, or what? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. its UTF-8 , VisualStudio and bare WindowsSDK.Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Aesthete as pointed out, you never clear the token vector once you're finished with it. This should be done, or change the token vector to utilize self-cleaning content like std::string or std::wstring.

Which brings me to the side-by-side below. Please review this against your existing code. There are a number of changes you'll want to compare. The one you will likely not see until you cmopile+run is the memory footprint difference, which may surprise you.

**Major Changes**

- Global `tokens` is now a vector of `std::wstring` rather than raw wchar_t pointers
- Uses `MultiByteToWideChar` to translate the input file.
- Allocates a `std::wstring` dynamically as the thread parameter. This removes one full copy of the file image. The thread is responsible for `delete`ing the `wstring` once finished parsing the content.
- Uses `_beginthreadex()` for starting the thread. The fundamental reason for this is because of the C/C++ runtime usage. In the past the runtime sets up various thread-local-storage that must be properly cleaned, and are so when using `_beginthreadex()`. It is almost identical to CreateThread(), but honestly I look forward to the day when MS has their stuff together and gives us `std::thread` officially like the rest of the civilized world.

**Minor/Meaningless Changes**

- Global variables are brought to local scope where appropriate. this means the only real global now is the `tokens` vector.
- The thread procedure now pushes substrings straight to the `tokens` vector.
- uses argv[1] for the filename (easy to debug that way, no other special reason). can be changed back to your hard-coded filename as needed.

I hope this gives you some ideas on cleaning this up, and more importantly, how yoy can do almost the entire task you're given without having to go `new` and `delete` nuts.

**Notes:** this does NOT check the input file for a byte-order-mark. I'm taking it on faith that your claim it is UTF8 is straight-up and doesn't have a BOM at the file beginning. If your input file does have a BOM, you need to adjust the code that reads the file in to account for this.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// global map of tokens
vector<wstring> tokens;

// format required by _beginthreadex()
unsigned int _stdcall ThreadProc(void *p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;
    std::string xml;
    std::wstring* pwstr = NULL;

    // check early exit
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " filename" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // use runtime library for reading the file content. the WIN32 CreateFile
    //  API is required for some things, but not for general file ops.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        if (dwFileSize > 0)
        {
            // allocate a string large enough for the whole file.
            std::string xml(dwFileSize, 0);
            DWORD bytesRead = 0;
            if (ReadFile(hFile, &xml.at(0), dwFileSize, &bytesRead, NULL) && (bytesRead == dwFileSize))
            {
                // invoke MB2WC to determine wide-char requirements
                int ires = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, xml.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
                if (ires > 0)
                {
                    // allocate a wstring for our thread parameter.
                    pwstr = new wstring(ires, 0);
                    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, xml.c_str(), -1, &pwstr->at(0), ires);

                    // launch thread. it own the wstring we're sending, including cleanup.
                    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, pwstr, 0, NULL);
                }
            }
        }

        // release the file handle
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    // wait for potential thread
    if (hThread != NULL)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    // report space taken by tokens
    size_t tokensSize = 0;
    for (vector<wstring>::const_iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
        tokensSize += it->size()+1;
    cout << "tokens count = " << tokens.size() << endl
         << "tokens size = "<< tokensSize <<" bytes" << endl;

    cin.get();  
}

// our thread parameter is a dynamic-allocated wstring.
unsigned int _stdcall ThreadProc(void *p)
{
    // early exit on null insertion
    if (p == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // use string passed to us.
    wstring* pEntireDB = static_cast<wstring*>(p);
    wstring::size_type last = 0;
    wstring::size_type next = pEntireDB->find(L'>',last);
    while(next != wstring::npos)
    {               
        tokens.push_back(pEntireDB->substr(last, next-last+1));
        last = next+1;
        next = pEntireDB->find(L'>', last);
    }

    // delete the wstring (no longer needed)
    delete pEntireDB;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory here, in the `do-while` loop:

```
szStr = new TCHAR[currentElement.length()+1];
```

And you never release it with the `delete` operator

Comment: if i will `delete`, how can I store the data?